# JavaScript how to convert object document.createElement to string

Tags: javascript

it is impossible to get a string of `createElement` that you would assign to a variable

```
var h1 = document.createElement("h1")
h1.innerHTML = "hello world"
alert(h1)
return "[object HTMLHeadingElement]"
```

when i use `appendChild` is work but i must use alert or other method

Comment: Why can't you just `alert(h1.innerHTML)`?

Comment: may be `h1.toString()` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

```
var h1 = document.createElement("h1")
h1.innerHTML = "hello world"
alert(h1.outerHTML)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7MVCc/)

Comment: I always forget about that. I think I'm still stuck at FF 4 ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to convert a DOM element to its HTML representation. Put it in a temporary container and access its `.innerHTML` property:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(h1);
var html = div.innerHTML;
```